# how to stop the page reloads while appending query string in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i want to append the query string in url,i tried but it is not working properly,like onloading the url `www.domain.com` in that time i want to append one string like `www.domain.com#login`,see below my tried code,string is appending in URl but page is getting loaded every seconds, i don't want page reloads

> MY Code

```
 var myURL = document.location;
 document.location = myURL + "#login"
```

Comment: use window.location rather than document.location !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) or [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) methods,  i.e.:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "new url");
```

OR

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/login");
```

Answer (score 0):

You use window.history to do a no reload change of querystring